# Jquery dropdown menu explanation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

i'm very new to javascript/jquery and don't quite understand it yet. I'm trying to learn dropdown menus using jquery and i found this w3school tutorial, however, i can't seem to understand some parts of the code http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown

I mean i understand pretty much everything up to this

```
    window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know what a for loop is and how it works but i don't understand how `i` work when it comes to divs from html file. For example   `var dropdowns`   has a div with a class of  `dropdown-content` in it. Then this var is used in a for loop with a length property, but i don't understand what is a length of that var..Is it 1? And then the line with `var openDropdown = dropdowns[i]`  this? The `var i` is `0` but what does it take from var dropdowns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
```

this  returns you an object that you can iterate with index (being 0,1... depending upon number of matched elements returned...)

also as value of i is initialized with 0...using dropdown[i] will exactly turn into dropdown[0] also if you have more matches it will do the job as well rather than writing the same thing all over again..

Hope thats helps...:D

Comment: So in the for loop, the dropdowns.length is what? 1? And what does dropdown[i] return? is it 'dropdown-content' div? Furthermore why is for loop used here, why not just IF function?

Comment: yes, `dropdown.length` return length of object array retrieved by statement `document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");` (here yes its has value 1 and its 'dropdown-content' div as you guessed) and the reason for loop could be you might have multiple drop-down menus not just one as in example so thats a generalized example and yes for single element testing withing 'if' was sufficient.